# Powerpoint email form with click

Tags: vba, powerpoint, form-submit

Hello I'm trying to build a VBA code to automatically send a copy of a completed form once the form has been completed. I have this form currently and I was able to write the following code for a word document:

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
Dim OL              As Object
Dim EmailItem       As Object
Dim Doc             As Document
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Set OL = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
Set EmailItem = OL.CreateItem(olMailItem)
Set Doc = ActiveDocument
Doc.Save

With EmailItem
.Subject = "SUBJECT LINE"
.Body = "BODY MESSAGE" & vbCrLf & _
"SECOND LINE BODY MESSAGE" & vbCrLf & _
"THIRD LINE BODY MESSAGE"
.To = "Receiver Email"
.Importance = olImportanceNormal
.Attachments.Add Doc.FullName
.Send
End With

Application.ScreenUpdating = True

Set Doc = Nothing
Set OL = Nothing
Set EmailItem = Nothing
End Sub
```

this worked fine with the word document, but now I have to do the following in powerpoint. I tried to use the following code below, but everytime I run this I get a compile error: Method or data member not found. Does anyone know why the below code doesn't work?

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
Dim OL              As Object
Dim EmailItem       As Object
Dim Powerpoint      As Presentation

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Set OL = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
Set EmailItem = OL.CreateItem(olMailItem)
Set Powerpoint = ActivePresentation
Powerpoint.Save

With EmailItem
.Subject = "SUBJECT LINE"
.Body = "BODY MESSAGE" & vbCrLf & _
"SECOND LINE BODY MESSAGE" & vbCrLf & _
"THIRD LINE BODY MESSAGE"
.To = "NAME@COMPANY.COM"
.Importance = olImportanceNormal
.Attachments.Add Doc.FullName
.Send
 End With

Application.ScreenUpdating = True

 Set Doc = Nothing
 Set OL = Nothing
 Set EmailItem = Nothing
 End Sub
```

Any help would be appreciated thanks!

Comment: Please add the line on which the error message appears

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems you are still using the `Doc` variable, when the name of the new variable for the presentation is `Powerpoint`. Take a look at the following lines:

`Doc.Save`

`.Attachments.Add Doc.FullName`

`Set Doc = Nothing`

Replace `Doc` with `Powerpoint` and your code should work.

Comment: Yup, that was what was acting up... thank you so much!